# Axios Promise result not copying to local function variable/local state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios, react-hooks

**Requirement:**

I require to make multiple API calls and then output the result onto the React Front-End.
I am using React hooks and not classes.

---

**Explanation of steps taken:**

In the view function (Function_V), I use a button to call a function (call it Function_A and it acts as the Service function), sending the parameters to that function. Function_A uses Axios to make a get call with the parameters and returns the required promise and the response content. I push parts of the returned output from Function_A onto a local array variable (in order to make a final response object). Taking few outputs from this Axios call, I make a function call to another function (Function_B) in Function_A's Axios call. This is another Axios call to get the rest of the required API response.

I successfully make the final response object in Function_A (utilizing both the outputs from Function_A and Function_B).
Finally, Function_A returns my custom response object as a promise.

---

**Problems and things I tried:**

1. I get the required response in the model function as a promise, but am unable to copy it to model function usual variables.

--> I tried making async and await (not good with the async-await and then-catch concept).

--> I created a local state in the model function and tried copying the response.

These are not working.

---

My issue is I cannot find a way to traverse the returned promise to access/store the response values in the local variables or set the local states with these values.

Below is the dummy code, please let me know if I am doing something wrong and how can I fix it.

Thank You All for taking out the time and helping me out! :)

---

**Dummy Code:**

***View.js***

```
import {Function_A} from ...;

function Function_V(){
    e.preventDefault();
    const [details, setDetails] = useState("");

    async function search(e){
       const r = await Function_A(param1,param2);
       console.log(r);
       setDetails(r);
    }

 return(
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={search}>
      <button type="submit"> Get User Address Details</button>
    </form>
  {details.length>1 &&(
    <div>{details}</div>
  </div>
  );
}
```

***Service.js***

```
import {Fucntion_B} from ...;

export async function Function_A(param1,param2){

    let url=param1+param2;
    let response={};
    e.preventDefault();
    let myAnswers=[];
    let address;

    const respon = await axios.get(url);
    address=respon.address;
         
    const w= await Function_B(address);
    for(let s=0;s<w.length;s++){
        myAnswer.push(w[s]);
    }

     respon={myAnswer,respon.address};
     return respon;    
}
```

***Helper.js***

```
export async function Function_B(param1_address){
    let url=param1_address;
    let count;
    const r2= await axios.get(url);
    count=r2.number;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Updated the code using Nitesh's advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

The errors were arising due to the fact that Axios requests were taking place later that the rendering of the components, the response data was not getting passed onto the original function in object format.

***Reason -*** ASYNC-AWAIT usage was done incorrectly. Upon correcting it will fix the error. The code in the question is fixed now.

***Note:***
Make sure to create a state in the view.js and set it to the response.
This way the result will be stored in the state and available for rendering.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using async-await is not correct. You are using it in a promise way which we should not. That is one of the reasons async-await was introduced to make users feel like synchronous calls.

```
export async myFun(){
 const addrResponse = await axios.get(url);
 const countResponse await axios.get(`${url}?param=${addrResponse.address}`)
 const number = countResponse.number;
}
```

This is the ideal way, in case you want to create new array for setting state just use `addrResponse` or `countResponse` directly.

Comment: Hey, Do you have any online demo where I can modify your code?

Comment: Function_A(param1,param2)
        .then((r)=>{
           console.log(r);
           setDetails(r);
        })

What is your expectation here?
What is r that you are setting as setDetails(r);

Comment: I want the API data that I fetched from Function_A (it contains selected data from Function_B combined) to be displayed. So I believe 'r' is the response from Function_A that should be stored in a local variable in Function_V. This will be rendered on the UI.

Comment: From your code, you are simply returning a response from FunctionA but what is the use of myAnswers and address there, it is not clear. Also, when you pass address to FunctionB, it is not being used there.

Comment: Oh Sorry, The parameters that are sent to both the functions are used to make the Axios calls. I have edited the code, pls check it.